# How can I install AWS Data sync agent on Hadoop cluster?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, amazon-s3, hadoop, aws-datasync

I have my hadoop sandbox set up on a Virtual Machine on Azure Cloud. I would like to install aws data sync agent on my hadoop sandbox so that I can create a task for data copy from my Hadoop cluster to AWS S3 using AWS Data Sync. Can someone guide me or point to me any resource if they have installed datasync agent on hadoop cluster.